# Is ListView used the same way as RecycleView?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to have self.search_results.data printed on my console, but this is not working. Am I using RecycleView the right way? The textbook I'm studying with is from 2014 and uses ListView. I found on the internet that ListView is deprecated. I can't seem to understand how the RecycleView actually works. I've read the documentation, but still can't see.

Kivy:

```
WeatherRoot:

<WeatherRoot>:
    AddLocationForm


<AddLocationForm>: 



    orientation: "vertical"#

    search_input: search_input
    search_results: search_results_list

    BoxLayout:

        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y:None

        TextInput:
            id: search_input
            size_hint_x: 50
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.search_location()


         Button:
             text: "Search"
             size_hint_x: 25
             on_press: root.search_location()

        Button:
             text: "Current Location"
             size_hint_x: 25

     RecycleView:
        id: search_results_list
        data: []
```

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.factory import Factory
import json


class WeatherApp(App):
    pass

class WeatherRoot(BoxLayout):
    pass


class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):

    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    search_results = ObjectProperty()

    # do something
    def search_location(self):

        search_template = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q= 
        {}&type=like"
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)

    def found_location(self, request, data):
        data =  json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) 
        else data
        cities = ["{} ({})".format(d['name'], d['sys']['country'])
              for d in data['list']]

        self.search_results.data= cities
        print(self.search_results.data)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

The strings in the list should be printed on the console

Answer (score 2):

## Kivy ListView » Deprecated

ListView is no longer defined in the recently released stable Kivy version 1.11.0.

## Kivy [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) » MVC ([Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))

> The view is generatad by processing the [data](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.data), essentially a list
>   of dicts, and uses these dicts to generate instances of the
>   [viewclass](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.viewclass) as required. Its design is based on the MVC
>   (Model-view-controller) pattern.
>
> - *Model*: The model is formed by [data](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.data) you pass in via a list of dicts.
> - *View*: The View is split across layout and views and implemented using adapters.
> - *Controller*: The controller determines the logical interaction and is implemented by [RecycleViewBehavior](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleViewBehavior).

## Solution

To create a RecycleView of selectable item, one needs to implement the following classes as part of the [viewclass](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.viewclass). The item is usually a widget e.g. [Label](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html), [Button](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html), or a group/row of widgets in a layout ([BoxLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html) or [GridLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html)).

### viewclass

- Selectabel recycle layout class, e.g. `SelectableRecycleBoxLayout()`, or `SelectableRecycleGridLayout()`
- Selectable widget class, e.g. `SelectableLabel()`, `SelectableButton()`, or `SelectableRow()`

### data

- Creates a list of dicts for [data](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.data)

## Example

The following example illustrates the equivalence of a ListView by using RecycleView. The [viewclass](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.viewclass) is a selectable [RecycleBoxLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout.html) of [Label](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html) widget. The app is using [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/)'s [API](https://openweathermap.org/api) to retrieve a sample weather data of London, GB (Great Britain).

### *Note:*

*To make calls to OpenWeatherMap using the real API point, you need an [API key (APPID)](https://openweathermap.org/appid).*

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.lang import Builder

import json


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected


class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):
    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    search_results = ObjectProperty()

    def search_location(self):
        search_template = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q={}&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22"
        # search_template = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q={}&typle=like&appid=xyz"
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)

    def found_location(self, request, data):
        data = json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data
        cities = ["{} ({})".format(d['name'], d['sys']['country']) for d in data['list']]
        self.search_results.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in cities]
        print(f"self.search_results.data={self.search_results.data}")


class WeatherRoot(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Weather App"

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
WeatherRoot:

<WeatherRoot>:
    AddLocationForm:

<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1) if self.selected else (.0, 0.9, .1, .3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.9, .1, .3)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<AddLocationForm>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    search_input: search_input
    search_results: search_results_list

    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y:None

        TextInput:
            id: search_input
            size_hint_x: 50
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            hint_text: 'Your city name'
            on_text_validate: root.search_location()


        Button:
            text: "Search"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.search_location()

        Button:
            text: "Current Location"
            size_hint_x: 25

    RecycleView:
        id: search_results_list

        viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'

        SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(26)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            multiselect: True
            touch_multiselect: True
```

## Output

[image: Data - Unselected]
[image: Data - Selected]